# ASP.NET get values from dynamic rows in table after PostBack

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, postback

I've got a table which is partially made up of dynamic rows (comes from a database)
Of course when I do a postback the rows are gone. I get that this can be fixed by adding the rows after every postback.
But here's the issue I'm having:
The rows contain some textboxes.
How do I get the filled in values back (which might have been changed by the user)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always find it in the Request.Form name/value collection.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.form.aspx